# ¿Cómo encontrar un determinado proceso de windows?

Tags: java, windows

Estoy haciendo una aplicación Java que tiene que arrancar un proceso en Windows como administrador y esperar a que éste termine antes de proseguir su ejecución.

En un principio, probé con esto:

```
String cmd[] = new String [3];
cmd [0] = "cmd";
cmd [1] = "/C";
cmd [2] = "runas /user:..."
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

pero no me funcionaba porque no hay manera (o yo no la encontré, ni probando ni buscando por mil sitios, incluida la versión inglesa de esta página) de pasarle después la contraseña de administrador (al lanzar un proceso como usuario administrador, desde una cuenta no administrativa, lógicamente pide el password).

Después, encontré que eso podría hacerlo con la biblioteca JNA. De esta manera:

```
boolean CreateProcessWithLogonW
    (WString lpUsername,
     WString lpDomain,
     WString lpPassword,
     int dwLogonFlags,
     WString lpApplicationName,
     WString lpCommandLine,
     int dwCreationFlags,
     Pointer lpEnvironment,
     WString lpCurrentDirectory,
     STARTUPINFO  lpStartupInfo,
     PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInfo);
```

Ésta es una biblioteca Java creada a partir de una de C# o de C++, no recuerdo bien. Con este método de una de las clases que incluye, se le pueden pasar el usuario, el password y la ruta de instalación. Después, he conseguido avanzar un poco más (usando igualmente la biblioteca JNA), así:

```
Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);   

Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();          

WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
try  
{
    while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry)) 
    {             
        System.out.println(processEntry.th32ProcessID + "\t" + Native.toString(processEntry.szExeFile));
    }
}
```

Así, consigo que me muestre todos los procesos de usuario, de forma que podría sacar cuál es el proceso que necesito esperar a que acabe. El problema, es que se trata de un proceso "javaw.exe" (al igual que mi propia aplicación), por lo que no puedo esperar a que acabe. Por tanto (y aquí viene, al fin, mi pregunta), creo que podría servirme si consiguiese sacar el usuario que lanzó este proceso (al realizarse desde una cuenta no administrativa, podría servir mandar a mi aplicación que espere hasta que el único proceso lanzado por el usuario "administrador" termine). ¿Conocéis alguna forma de conseguir esto?

Comment: Todos los procesos tiene un PID asignado, cuándo lo lanzas lo puedes guardar y luego hacer un loop mientre ese pid siga existiendo :)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me ha abierto los ojos sobre la forma de hacerlo ;) Pero hay otro problema, la clase "PROCESS_INFORMATION" de JNA me puede devolver (mediante un atributo) el PID, pero lo hace en un formato raro (DWORD). Este formato se puede escribir por pantalla (System.out...), pero no me permite guardarlo en un String para hacer lo que necesito. Sabes de qué forma se podría hacer?

Comment: DWORD es un int (formato windows). Haz un cast a int : `(int) PIDEnDWORD` y ya está!

Comment: Lo conseguí!! Mil gracias ;)

Comment: ¿Puedes contestar a tu propia pregunta con la solución para así poder compartirla con la comunidad? Un saludo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo con el `PID` del proceso buscado. Con este método:

```
    public boolean jambo_loco (int pid)
    {

        Kernel32 kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary(Kernel32.class, W32APIOptions.UNICODE_OPTIONS);
        Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference processEntry = new Tlhelp32.PROCESSENTRY32.ByReference();          

        WinNT.HANDLE snapshot = kernel32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(Tlhelp32.TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, new WinDef.DWORD(0));
        try  
        {
            int i = 0;

            int size = processEntry.dwSize.intValue();

            while (kernel32.Process32Next(snapshot, processEntry) && i < size) 
            {             
                if (processEntry.th32ProcessID.intValue() == pid)
                    return true;
                i++;
            }

        }
        finally 
        {
            kernel32.CloseHandle(snapshot);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Desde fuera, con un bucle, llamo de nuevo a este método cada vez que este devuelve `true` (la ejecución debe continuar sólo cuando el proceso termine).